# Email loop causing Notes to crash (Embed object = issue)

Tags: vba, lotus-notes, email-attachments

[image]I have the following code which is always causing IBM(LOTUS) Notes to crash at the .EmbedObject line

```
Call body.EmbedObject(1454, "", Attachment)
```

This is the part of the main code. At this point there are 2 dictionaries which are converted to arrays and then into e-mail strings. The call to the EMAIL sub-routine is below.

Anyone have any idea what could be causing this or know a fix?? All variables are declared at the public level in the main module with string type

This works fine with a simple loop macro that I used to integrate into my macro (basic for loop calling the email routine every iteration, with declaring the document and body each time)

thank you

```
Private Sub SaveFilestoDesktop_andEmail()

'Saves file to desktop with date stamp and e-mails to the user

Dim WB As Workbook
Dim wks As String
Dim fname As String, i As Integer
Dim EmailArray_PC() As Variant, EmailArray_PM() As Variant
EmailArray_PM = dict.keys()
EmailArray_PC = dict_2.keys()
i = 1

Subj = "Items to Review"
'EmailBody = "The following items have been flagged as possible cost errors " & _
'"by process of identifying variances of +/- 30 % compared to the current average cost. " & _
'"Please see attachment and review for internal purposes." & vbLf & _
'vbLf & VBA.Format(Now, "m/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM")

On Error GoTo errhandlr

    For Each WB In Workbooks

    'Set the first sheet name of each WB to the wks variable
    wks = WB.ActiveSheet.Name

        'If unsaved workbook (only part of the above sub procedures)
        If Left(WB.Name, 4) = "Book" Then

            fname = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\" & Replace(WB.Worksheets(1).Name, ".", "") & "- " & VBA.FormatDateTime(Date, vbLongDate) _
            & " (" & Format(Time, "hhmmss AMPM") & ")"

            With WB

        '    If Dir(fname) <> "" Then
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False

            'Save the file as an .xlsx to the default user path
            .SaveAs Filename:=fname, FileFormat:=51

            Application.DisplayAlerts = True

            On Error Resume Next               'if tries to e-mail but it fails (such as for "blank")

            'Setting up parameters for e-mailing
            SendTo = Right(EmailArray_PM(i), Len(EmailArray_PM(i)) - WorksheetFunction.Find(",", EmailArray_PM(i)) - 1) & "_" & _
            Left(EmailArray_PM(i), WorksheetFunction.Find(",", EmailArray_PM(i)) - 1) & "@quadra.ca"
            SendCC = Right(EmailArray_PC(i), Len(EmailArray_PC(i)) - WorksheetFunction.Find(",", EmailArray_PC(i)) - 1) & _
            "_" & Left(EmailArray_PC(i), WorksheetFunction.Find(",", EmailArray_PC(i)) - 1) & "@quadra.ca"
            Attachment = WB.Name

            'Call e-mail maco in Other module
            Call Email_using_Notes_Call(SendTo, SendCC, Attachment)

            'Increment i by 1
            i = i + 1

            On Error GoTo 0

            'Close the Workbook, go to next WB
            .Close

            End With

            'Clear the filename to save with for next WB
            fname = Empty

        End If

    Next WB

Exit Sub

Erase EmailArray_PC: Erase EmailArray_PM
Set dict = Nothing: Set dict_2 = Nothing         'clear dict objs

errhandlr:
MsgBox err.Number & Space(2) & err.Description
err.Clear
'MsgBox err.Number & Space(2) & err.Description
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Call to EMAIL loop:

```
Sub Email_using_Notes_Call(ByVal SendTo As String, _
Optional ByVal SendCC As String, Optional ByVal Attachment As String)

On Error Resume Next

'Creates the Notes Document (e-mail)
Set doc = db.CreateDocument

With doc
.Subject = Subj
.SendTo = SendTo
.CopyTo = SendCC
.Importance = "1"
End With

'Creating the body of the Notes document
Set body = doc.CreateRichTextItem("Body")

'Formatting the body of the text
Call body.AppendText("The following items have been flagged as possible cost errors by process of identifying variances of +/- 30 %")
Call body.AddNewline(1)               '--> This adds a line feed to the body
Call body.AppendText("compared to the current average cost. Please see attachment and review for internal purposes  ")
Call body.EmbedObject(1454, "", Attachment)  --> this is where it crashes                               'EMBED_ATTACHMENT[1454 = embed attachment, 1453 = embed object]
Call body.AddNewline(2)
Call body.AppendText(Now())
Call doc.Send(False)            'False is the variable that indicates attach form or not (always false in our case)

'Clearing for next document
Set body = Nothing
Set doc = Nothing

On Error GoTo -1

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm wondering if it could be because I didn't add the Lotus Domino Objects to my object references?

Comment: No, you never would have gotten that far into the code if there was a problem with the Domino objects.

Comment: That said, I don't see your declarations and initialization for db, doc, etc. It would be useful to see whether you are using the Domino back-end objects, or the Notes OLE objects.

Comment: Figured it out guys, thanks!

Comment: Well, then.... What was it? If you come to the community for advice, it's only fair that you give back. Someone else may encounter the very same problem and find this question.

Comment: It was the attachment of the current workbook. I changed this to a seperate file and it worked fine. So I altered the code to save close and then attach.

Answer (score 2):

I think this issue is caused what you are trying to embed.

The document you are trying to Embed is the Excel workbook itself. You have the workbook open, so it cannot necessarily be read due to a lock.

Something that might help you definitely find out if that's the reason:

1. Try to add another file as the attachment that isn't open and see if it works, as a test.
2. Change the On Error Resume Next located in your e-mailing function to an error handler, like you have in the function above it.

Comment: Good suggestions. I tried step 1 and it still threw an exception error. I added a handler within the Email sub , and it still isn't liking that one line of code for some reason . Seems odd because Attachment is a publicly declared variable and is equal to the wb name.